# filter unique list from json

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I have two drop downs, one is street and the other is apt. Street and apt are the properties of address class. I have a unique_seq_no for each address, so i store it in a HashMap.

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, Address> addressMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Address >();
Property prop = new Property();
    ArrayList<Property> ap = new ArrayList<Property>();
    for(Offices of: offList)
    {
    Address ad = new Address();
    ad.setStreet(of.getAdd());
    ad.setApt(of.getUnit());
    ad.setUnique_seq_no(of.getSequence());
    addressMap.put(of.getSequence(),ad);
    prop.setAddSeq(of.getSequence());
    prop.setAdd(of.getAdd());
    ap.add(prop)
    }
```

This returns a JSON of,

```
   [{seq:23456,add:1234 NW st,apt:201},{seq:45678,add:1234 NW st,apt:202},
     {seq:57689,add:6785 NW st,apt:203}]
```

Issues, 
1. In the street drop down it displays duplicate add.

2. Once the user selects the add from the drop down(for eg: 1234 NW st- the repeated add), it picks the seq in which it stored and displays only that apt.

I want to create a map with street as key, and a list of apts as the value. Since street is duplicated, how do we achieve this.

Comment: You seem to be adding the same `prop` to the `ap` list multiple times. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here i how you can get to the required solution. I believe you are correct till "addressMap" is populated with key as sequenceNo & value as "Address" Object which holds street, apartment & sequence number.

Next thing you will need to do is iterate through adressMap & populate anotherMap which holds key as street (which should be unique) & value as "List of Apartment". This is how you can take this forward.

ArrayList ap = new ArrayList();

```
    for (Offices of : offlist) {
        Address ad = new Address();
        ad.setStreet(of.getAddress());
        ad.setApt(of.getUnit());
        ad.setUnique_seq_no(of.getSequence());
        addressMap.put(of.getSequence(), ad);
    }

    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> finalMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

    for (Entry<String, Address> entry : addressMap.entrySet()) {

        Address address= entry.getValue();
        finalMap.put(address.getStreet(),getList(address.getStreet() , finalMap , address.getApt()));
    }
```

"getList" is the method which takes care of adding list of Apartment to the same street key if already exists.

Now you will need to below code to populate finalMap which consists of unique street as key & list of apartments as value.

```
private static ArrayList<String> getList(String street,HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> adressMap , String apt){

    if(adressMap != null && adressMap.get(street) != null){
        ArrayList<String> list =  adressMap.get(street);
        list.add(apt);
        return list;
    }else{
        ArrayList<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(apt);
        return list;
    }
}
```

If you convert the finalMap to JSON string, below will be format of string you will see.

{"678 NW":["101"],"124 NW":["101"],"1234 NW":["102","103"]}